# using hmm in matlab for hand gesture recognition

Tags: matlab, gesture-recognition, hidden-markov-models

Please i need help on implementing hmm for hand gestures using the stats toolbox in matlab. I have a sequence of frames (static images) that represent each dynamic gesture. I have converted each frame into a feature vector using the contour information of the image.
Now my problem is how to use this information to train the hmm and subsequently recognize unknown gestures. i have a little knowledge of hmm but what i don't understand here is

1. what are my states
2. what are the emission symbols?
3. how do i guess the initial transition and emission matrices?
4. and the sequence in which i should use the matlab functions.

I have 10 different static hand shapes and any 3 combinations of these static shapes forms a dynamic gesture.
I will appreciate your help a lot, thanks